# React Router changes the url but does not load the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React Router is changing the url but is not loading the component.

And once the url is changed and if the page gets refreshed, the correct component corresponding to the url is shown.

This is the code :

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import {  Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Home} from '../src/Views/Home';
import {Test} from './Views/Home';
import App from '../../../src/App'

const Root = () => (
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>  
      <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />


</Switch>
</Router>
);  


export default Root;
```

There are no console errors.

Comment: How are you navigating to another url?

Comment: I am navigating using  <Link to="/test" />

Comment: errors in console?

Comment: How are you importing router? can you show the whole component with imports and exports?

Comment: Please paste more code from your app.

Comment: i updated the code including the imports also